# How to change "attachment_id" in attachment permarlink?

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I changed attachment permalink by `add_filter('attachment_link','my_media_url');`
from

```
http://domain.com/?attachment_id=123
```

to:

```
http://domain.com/?media=123
```

**The change is successful. But, with the new URL, the page is not found**. Some suggest rewrite rules like: [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/changing-attachment-urls)

```
'media/(.+)' => 'index.php?attachment=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
```

I tried, it doesn't work in my case. Instead of modify patterns before or after "attachment_id", I want to **replace "attatchment_id" with "media" and keep all the other stuffs unchanged.**
Is this a question of rewrite, or should I study something else?
I tried this, not working either:

```
function attachment_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
     $rule = array(
         '/?media=' => 'index.php?attachment_id=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
     );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rule + $wp_rewrite->rules; } add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'attachment_rewrite' );
```

Comment: Does this help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14931/10691

Comment: No, that rule remove "?" and modify "_id" to "/id". I want to keep "?" and modify"attachment_id" to "media"

Comment: Hmm... I meant, modify that code to your needs. Can you try this and see if it works? http://pastebin.com/8715TTVi

Comment: Thanks for the code! But it can't find the page either.

Comment: "Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1 in ....\wp-includes\class-wp.php on line 201"

Comment: Let me give it one last try: http://pastebin.com/20zNqSsU — see if it works.

Comment: still not working. this time no error message.