# Change the Permalink for wordpress attachment

Tags: attachments, seo, rewrite-rules

My attachments are currently rewritten from
`http://localhost/?attachment_id=3` to
`http://localhost/images/image-title` using @Bainternet's answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14924/pretty-urls-or-permalinks-for-attachments#answer-14931).

```
 $new_rules['images/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?attachment_id=$matches[1]';
```

However, wordpress still refers to the link as the default `http://localhost/?attachment_id=3`.  Wordpress functions such as the_permalink, get_attachment_url, get_attachment_image_src, etc. all use the default format of `http://localhost/?attachment_id=3`.

I am able to access the image as intended if I manually type in the rewritten format `http://localhost/images/image-title`.

How can I get wordpress to use my custom rewrite for the permalink especially on the admin page?

**EDIT:**  reworded question for specificity and correctness:
How do I override `the_permalink` to use the format `/images/image-title` instead of `/?attachment_id=ID`?
I can get image-title using `$post->post_title`.

**EDIT #2:**
For anyone reading this question in the future, I found it best to use `$post->post_name` for the link to insure uniqueness.
`/images/post_title`

Comment: that rule works with the attachment ID, how do you get the title from that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your rule works with the attachment ID, so I'm not sure how you're using the title, but the answer is almost identical in either case. The filter you want is `attachment_link`:

```
function wpd_attachment_link( $link, $post_id ){
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    return home_url( '/images/' . $post->post_title );
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpd_attachment_link', 20, 2 );
```

Change `$post->post_title` to `$post->ID` to put the ID in the URL instead of title.

Comment: Thanks.  This will work with the attachment link function.  Will it also work with get_attachment_link()?  I will try it.  I prefer to use the_permalink() which relies on get_attachment_link() but I don't want to lose some of the other functionality of get_attachment_link().  Really just trying to replace `$link = home_url( '/?attachment_id=' . $post->ID );` with `$link = home_url( '/images/' . $post->post_title );`

Comment: All output of attachment URLs ultimately get run through that filter. If you want it applied in some cases and not others, you'll have to conditionally add/remove the filter. You could check if `is_admin()` first to have it only applied in admin screens, or add the filter in your template to only apply it for specific front end stuff.

Comment: Tried it.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks.  Was trying to override the wrong function.  Much appreciated.

Comment: All works fine until I change to $post->ID. I don't have control over image names and spaces in images names gives 404 error. But when I change to $post->ID I also get 404 errors. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Some other way to Change the permalink url

```
function ro_remove_attachment_title_caption( $attach_id ){
 $args = array(
   'ID'          => $attach_id,
   'post_name'   => "permalinkName",
 );
 wp_update_post( $args );
}
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'ro_remove_attachment_title_caption', 10, 1 );
```

It works in the context of the Plugin: [remove OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA from caption and title by Image upload](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-olympus-digital-camera-from-caption-and-title-by-image-upload/)