# Custom permalink for attachment

Tags: filters, url-rewriting, attachments

I am trying to rewrite my permalinks for attachments, which would open the `attachment.php` post.  I found some code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142600/36204) and have modified it to look like this:

```
function wpd_attachment_link( $link, $post_id ){
    $mimes  = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/bmp', 'image/tiff', 'image/x-icon' );
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( in_array( $post->post_mime_type, $mimes ) ){
        return home_url( '/images/' . $post->post_name . '/' );
    } else {
        return home_url( '/files/' . $post->post_name . '/');
    }
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpd_attachment_link', 20, 2 );
```

What I intend to do is have all images open with an `images` URL and all other files to open with a `files` URL.  I am setting up the `attachment.php` page to fit my design, but the page does exist.  Before I used the `attachment_link` filter, I could see the page.  Now, the new URL format returns a 404 error, and the old URL format (standard post URL with the attachment's `post_name` variable appended) redirects to the new URL, which returns a 404 error.  Is there a way where I can display the required page with `/images/` and `/files/`?

Comment: Go into `Settings->Permalinks` and just click on `Save Changes`. You may just need to reset your rewrite rules.

Comment: you are changing the link but not telling WP where that link should go. you have to add rewrite rules. https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule